# Need explanation of win API "Asynchronous Procedure Calls" relative to .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, synchronization, apc

I have a bug. In WinForm .NET2.0 application my HeavyFunction can be called from mouse click event handlers. So, When I'm starting fast clicking  I have crash on file writing because of HeavyFunction entered second time.

My solution. I remembered the things relative to APC and decided to synchronize the things fairly. I.e. I want to exclude APC effects in the HeavyFunction. So, I used ThreadPool. For synchronization I tried to use SyncLock (Visual Basic). And failed. Mutexes don't work either.
I simply cannot understand how my HeavyFunction can be called from the same thread twice at a time. But it does. I thought that if I use ThreadPool then I force every call be executed on different thread.

The definition of APC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. 
Here is "Thread Synchronization Fairness in the CLR" by Jeffrey Richter (makes me sick): 
http://codeguru.earthweb.com/csharp/.net/net_general/threads/article.php/c4647/Thread-Synchronization-Fairness-in-the-CLR.htm

EDIT: It seems that I found the reason of crash exception. It's antivirus AVG. Probably he  considers suspicious activity when somebody clicks very fast and it causes fast file open/write operations. Or it slows down my PC so much. Anyway I cannot reproduce crash when AVG disabled. Although ProcMon shows that AVG access the file while enabled.

Finally, can somebody explain APC to me? Namely, can APC lead to double enter to the same function in the same thread? 
I understood that it can from this [text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):
"An asynchronous procedure call (APC) is a function that executes asynchronously in the context of a particular thread. When an APC is queued to a thread, the system issues a software interrupt. The next time the thread is scheduled, it will run the APC function. "

I'm afraid to die without this understanding.

Comment: Does HeavyFunction access the same file every time?

Comment: Yes, it does access the same file every time

Comment: Then you really don't want/need multiple threads -- you only want one call accessing this file at a time.  ChrisWue's answer of using a queue is probably the ideal solution.

Comment: APC is very low-level, it isn't directly exposed in managed code beyond ThreadPool.BindHandle.  You are chasing a rabbit down a hole, post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks. You are the only man who understood me. Please see my edit of the question.

Comment: @alehro - The tone of your comments in general is probably deterring people from trying to help you.  There's no reason to get snippy because someone didn't understand what you were asking.  The fact that multiple people misunderstood your question might be a hint that it needs to be reworded.

Comment: If they cannot understand what about I am asking, why they are answering? I could understand such behavior if my question was old and without answers. But they started flooding just in minutes after I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because Win32 messages are implicitly reentrant. This is particularly true in .NET because the runtime may pump on your behalf whenever your UI thread blocks.

The normal way to work around this behavior is to either disable the controls while the long-running event handler is executing, or keep a queue of actions to run instead of kicking off another handler each time.

APCs are a red herring. They can "borrow" a thread in an alertable wait (which the .NET runtime usually uses for blocked UI threads), but an APC will not invoke a UI event handler (at least, I cannot think of any situation that would cause this).

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me whether you want many calls at the same time... you could just disabled the button while the heavyFunction executes?

**EDIT**

Since it seems you need every call handled, you should uses a Queue that stores every call, and a thread that executes them one by one.

Comment: +1 This is actually a good answer since you didn't specify whether or not you needed each event handled.  If you need to guarantee that each event is handled, then you should specify that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
class yourform {
   Queue<somedata> queue = new Queue<somedata>();
   Thread caller;   
   private bool Closing {get;set;}

   public yourform() {
     /// initcomponents bla bla
     Thread t = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate() {
        while (!Closing) {
          lock (queue) {
             if (queue.Peek()) {
               somedata data = queue.Dequeue();
               HeavyFunction(data); // add invoke if required
             }
          }
        }
     }).Start();
     caller = t;
   }

   ~yourform() {
     Closing = true;
     caller.Join();
   }
   void clickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     somedata data = new somedata();
     queue.Queue(data);
   }
}
```

Edit: you did not tag Visual basic so I did not notice , but you can use an online vb to c# translator...

Answer (score 1):

From your comment you say you want the events to be processed one by one in the order they come in. This sounds like a queue. Have a look at this question: [How to reuse threads in .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826981/how-to-reuse-threads-in-net-3-5) The accepted answer shows a worker queue implementation. If you use it with `workerCount = 1` then you have a queue being processed by one thread and the events will be processed in the order they enter the queue.

Comment: Where I said about button? I have complex control. Which cannot be disabled.

Comment: I don't want to skip events like your solution suggests. Hey, guys, read the question, please. I need explanation on heavy stuff, don't flood please.

Comment: Ok, you said something about a mouse click event. From your description it sounds like your only want one execution of `HeavyProc` at a given time (so it's not executed multiple times parallel). Is that right or wrong? Maybe you can post some source code to show what you do at the moment and what you try to achieve

Comment: I want all mouse click events to be fully processed one by one. In the same order as they were generated. That's why I'm trying to use thread pool.

Comment: You can't use the ThreadPool for that. If you enqueue work items they will be assigned to threads but you have no influence on the order in which they will be processed

Comment: SuperQueue uses .Net's syncronization primitives. So, the APC will work and double enter to function by the same thread is still possible. I'm wondering, do you know how APC works? That is what about the question from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your HeavyFunction cannot be called twice on the same thread at the same time.  A single thread can only perform one function at a time -- it has to return before it is called again in the same thread.

I'm not sure what is going on, but if your mouse click event handler is creating a new object (with HeavyFunction), then a lock won't help you.

Does HeavyFunction access the same file each time?  If so, then a thread pool won't work either because all the threads will still be trying to access a single file.

I think the best solution is to use a queue like ChrisWise suggests.