# Reuse an awaiting thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

So, as everyone knows, frameworks like asp.NET, WPF and WinRT manage one or more threads for you. In asp.NET, the framework pools a set of threads that take requests from a queue and process them. In WPF, the framework manages the UI thread for you, which takes messages from the message pump.

This can be achieved with a simple producer/consumer approach, where the consuming thread executes a `while(true)` loop, takes messages from a queue and uses a message handler (the user's code) to execute them. Simple enough. You can find a basic implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828863/857807

With the introduction of the async/await semantics, you can delegate CPU/IO-intensive work to some other thread, and leave the (for example) UI thread responsive. This means that the UI thread will keep taking messages from the pump.

My question is: starting with the aforementioned basic implementation, how would the consumer implement this? How would you know that the message handler is asynchronously awaiting for another thread to complete and, therefore, take another message from the queue? I'm sure I'm missing something big here.

Comment: Are you asking how the WPF/etc UI threads do this, or how you would do it yourself on a specific thread?

Comment: I'm sure the framework's actual implementation is a bit overkill for me, I'd just like to know the gist of it. I'm not trying to implement it myself, but I'd like to know how I would do it if I wanted to, out of curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that when an `async` method yields in an `await`, it actually *returns* to its caller. So, from the perspective of the main loop, the method has completed.

Later on, when the awaitable operation completes, it schedules the remainder of the `async` method to the captured context. In the cases you mentioned (ASP.NET / WPF / WinRT), the context is a `SynchronizationContext`. In the UI frameworks (WPF / WinRT / WinForms / etc), that `SynchronizationContext` is tied to the message queue.

So if you want an `async`-compatible "main loop", you'd need to implement a custom `SynchronizationContext` that allows scheduling delegates back to that main loop.

For more information:

- My [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) describes how `async` and `await` methods return and capture context.
- My [`SynchronizationContext` MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) describes the relevant portions of that type, and how it's used throughout the .NET framework.
- My [AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) has an `async`-compatible "main loop", including [documentation](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext), [source](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20%28NET4,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/AsyncContext.cs), and [unit tests](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Unit%20Tests/Tests/AsyncContextUnitTests.cs).

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! I completely forgot that the message handler is often an `async void` method! Which, naturally, means that the method will return when it hits the first `await` keyword, making the consumer carry onto the next message. It all seems so obvious now * . *

Comment: @dcastro It will do that *regardless* of whether it's `void` or non-void.  That said, you should pretty much never have an `async void` method unless you *need* to for it to be a handler for an event.

Comment: Also, great links, I'll take a close look at your library.

Comment: @Servy `async void` is useful if you need to serialize operations. `await OpenTheDoor(); await WalkThrough(); await CloseTheDoor();`

Comment: @RaymondChen: Not at all. `async void` does not provide any "serialization" beyond what `async Task` does, and `async void` methods cannot be composed (`await`ed).

Comment: @RaymondChen What you just described *wouldn't* work if the methods were `async void`.  They would need to be `async Task` for it to *work*.